# Neural Network Regression produces negative values in output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression

I have 45 input variables, to predict 10 output variables. All vaues is the output are positve. I have created a Neural Network model using Tensorflow Keras. All values in the training data set are scaled from 0 to 1. If I use the function below which creates a keras.functional () architecture I get some negative predictions on only positve training and test data. I need to model all output variables in one model, because they are correlating strongly and are decreasing and I want the model to learn from the correlation. I don't know if this works, though. I have tried many architectures to get rid of negative prediction values but nothing worked.

Is there any reason why I'm obtaining negative values in my predictions? I'm using Min-Max scaling on the input data and then reverting it to the original scale after making predictions.
Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

The activation functions for the two hidden layers are relu with each 512 nodes. The output function is linear.

```
def build_multi_output_model():
    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))

    # Loop through units and activation functions for each layer
    x = input_layer
    for units, activation_function in zip(units_list, activation_functions):
        x = layers.Dense(units=units, activation=activation_function)(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(0.01)(x)

    # Create multiple output layers
    outputs = []
    for i in range(y.shape[1]):
        output_layer = layers.Dense(1, name=f'output_{i}')(x)
        outputs.append(output_layer)

    model = keras.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=outputs)

    optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['mse'])
    return model

   model1 = build_multi_output_model()
   model1.fit(X_train, [y_train[:, i] for i in range(y.shape[1])], epochs=epochs,         batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your predictions are logits and in order to get real predictions you needs sigmoid or softmax function it depends on your task.

```
tf.keras.activations.sigmoid(x)
```

Comment: Thank You! This was exactly what I was looking for. I was blind

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would try to use non-linear non-negative activation function such as ReLU:

```
keras.activations.relu()
```

If this doesn't help - I would try to apply non-negative constraints on the weights of your network:

```
output_layer = layers.Dense(1, kernel_constraint=keras.constraints.NonNeg(), name=f'output_{i}')(x)
```

Good luck!